# Long-held TCP sessions in an ASMX client

Tags: web-services, tcp, asmx

I have an ASP.NET application which talks to a third-party SOAP web service. My application uses an ASMX client proxy (i.e. System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol). The third-party service uses WCF, although I don't expect that makes much difference.

I should note that we're using .NET 3.5 SP1.

We haven't customised the proxy or done anything unusual - we're just making standard web service requests and getting back the results. We have encapsulated the proxy reference within a using block so it will get disposed after the response is received.

We've been told that our application is behaving strangely in its use of TCP sessions. Instead of opening a new TCP session for each request from a new proxy instance (which is what I would have expected it to do), it's apparently keeping several connections alive and re-using them. This is causing some issues at the third party end, as they are expecting us to be using multiple sessions.

Is this a known behaviour for the SoapHttpClientProtocol client proxy? If so, is there any way we can override it so that each request results in a new TCP session?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See "[Ways to Customize your ASMX Client Proxy](http://johnwsaundersiii.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!600A2BE4A82EA0A6!435.entry)". You'll see how to set the `KeepAlive` property of the `HttpWebRequest` used to make your requests.